# Nginx constant writes causes CPU I/O wait

Tags: nginx, iowait

I'm running nginx/1.20.1 on a G9 CentOS  7 machine for serving static video files with the following specs:

- 32 cores of CPU
- 32GB of RAM
- 6TB of HDD storage

Nginx config:

```
user root;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;
worker_rlimit_nofile 30000;
events {
    worker_connections 2024;
    use epoll;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    directio            16m;
#    output_buffers     2 32m;
#    aio                        threads;
    sendfile_max_chunk 512k;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   120;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # allow the server to close connection on non responding client, this will free up memory
    reset_timedout_connection on;
    # request timed out -- default 60
    client_body_timeout 60;
    # if client stop responding, free up memory -- default 60
    send_timeout 30;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;
    client_max_body_size 200m;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

}
```

conf.d:

```
server{
    listen 80;
    server_name  mydomain.com;
    charset utf-8;
    sendfile   on;
    tcp_nopush on;

    fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
    client_header_timeout 600;
    client_body_timeout 600;
    client_max_body_size 0;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/static.access_log main;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/static.error_log error;


   location / {
     proxy_pass http://localhost:7070;
     proxy_http_version 1.1;
     proxy_set_header Connection "";
    }

    # prevent nginx from serving dotfiles (.htaccess, .svn, .git, etc.)
    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }


}

server {
    set $base_path "/mypath";
    set $news_video_path "/mypath2";
    listen 7070;
    server_name localhost;
    location ~ /upload/videos/(.*) {
        alias $news_video_path/$1;
    }

    location ~ /video/(.*) {
        alias $base_path/video/$1;
    }


    access_log /var/log/nginx/localhost.access_log main;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/localhost.error_log error;
}
```

The problem is when the nginx process starts, the CPU load average increases as well till it reaches 100% of usage. I used the `htop` to see what process is consuming the CPU and there was no such process. Then I head out to our monitoring dashboard and found out it's the I/O Wait that causes a High Load Average:

[image]

Then used the `iotop` to see which process has an IO wait time:

[image]

The strange thing is that Nginx worker processes have a high Disk Write rate. Sometimes the `Total DISK WRITE` reaches the number 100MB/s but the `Actual Disk Write` doesn't have the same behavior. I also should mention that I don't use the Nginx Cache so these write operations are not related to caching. Disabling the Nginx logging didn't help either.

How can I debug it? Why is nginx writing that much data on Disk?

Comment: do you have something specific about this problem in your `access.log` or `error.log`?

Comment: @user973254 There are some errors related to upstream like `readv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer)` and `connect() failed (111: Connection refused)`

Comment: okay, what kind of file system do you use (with OS version) and what types and sizes of files do you serve from your disk?

Comment: also you may want to use nginx `proxy_buffer` and `proxy_cache` if you know exactly what to serve and have access to quicker storage option

Comment: @user973254 We are using LVM to manage our partitions on Centos 7. The served files are different in size, but they are usually about 30MB - 200MB. Unfortunately, there is no quicker storage option. But I still don't understand what the nginx is writing on the disk.

Comment: I suppose it's cache related issue. I will try to put my thoughts about that into question answer after some time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the missing Nginx `multi_accept` directive. Since we were serving video files and they were typically huge by size, Nginx couldn't respond to new connections if it was serving video files to some users.

Adding `multi_accept on` to the `events` block solved the issue.

```
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
    multi_accept       on;
    use epoll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all create `/var/cache/nginx` directory and give full read/write access to your `nginx`system user, then add this directive in nginx `http {}` context:

```
proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=my_zone:10m max_size=300m inactive=1d;
proxy_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";
```

Then add these to `server {}` context or `location {}` you've wanted to serve your cache from:

```
proxy_cache my_zone;
proxy_cache_valid 200 1d;
proxy_cache_valid 404 302 1m;
proxy_cache_revalidate on;
proxy_cache_bypass $http_cache_control;

proxy_http_version 1.1;

add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
add_header X-Proxy-Cache  $upstream_cache_status;
```

Did not test, but you should get the idea and test it.

Comment: We don't want to use Nginx Cache because we are behind a CDN server and there are not that many requests hitting our NGINX server. CDN would do the caching.

Comment: @Erfun you should have been mentioning CDN usage in your question then. Best way to get clue what is your problem is to `debug`, would be perfect for you if it is possible for single connection: https://nginx.org/en/docs/debugging_log.html

Comment: `multi_accept` did the job!